# S3 access key on multiple clients

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Can I use an Amazon S3 access key/secret on a desktop app? I mean, can multiple clients use the same access key concurrently to upload files to a bucket? Is there a limit?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you can have concurrent processes sharing the same access keys.

Comment: Yes, but it's bad practice to have multiple clients using the same credentials and it's bad practice for apps to have hardcoded IAM credentials.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by a 'desktop app'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access Keys are not 'logins'. Rather, each time that AWS receives an API call, it verifies whether the request should be allowed. It does this by matching the credentials with an IAM User or Role, then checks the associated policies to determine whether the API call is permitted.

There is **no concept of a 'login' within this process**. So, yes, an unlimited number of systems could make API calls with the same credentials without impacting each other.

The AWS Management Console is slightly different in that you do *login* to the console, and then the console makes API calls on your behalf. **Multiple users can be logged in** with the same credentials simultaneously in the console.